# JMeter Thread Execution should get stop when it goes to If controller

Tags: jmeter

I have a scenario in JMeter like if the transaction enters into the if loop controller, then the execution should get stop when the all the requests in the if controller gets completed.
It should not execute the calls which are outside the controller.

How to achieve this case? can somebody suggest an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Add [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler as the last request in the If Controller and configure it like:

   [image]
2. Or add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as the last request in the If Controller and put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   ctx.getThread().stop()
   SampleResult.setIgnore()
   ```

   [image]

   See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article to learn what do these `ctx` and `SampleResult` guys mean.
3. That's it, if thread enters the If Controller it will execute Sampler1, Sampler 2 and Sampler 3 and then stop. If thread doesn't enter the If Controller it will execute Sampler 1 and Sampler 4.